# Unable to change source of text dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault;
                $("a").click(function (event) {
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#bg").slideDown(1000, function () {
                        $("#content").hide().load(url + ' #content', function () {
                            $("#bg").slideUp(1000);
                            $(this).show();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            nav ul li {
                display: inline;
                padding: 0px 20px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #bg {
                position: fixed;
                top: 100px;
                transition: all 2s;
                background-color: gray;
                z-index:25;
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
                <h2>DEMO</h2>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="first.html#content">First</a>
                        <li>
                            <a href="second.html#content">Second</a>
                            <li>
                                <a href="third.html#content">Third</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="all">
                <div id="bg"></div>
                <p id="content">banna third Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
                    erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
                    ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
                    consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
                    accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
                    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta
                    nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat
                    facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis
                    in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores
                    legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus,
                    qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera
                    gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas
                    humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi,
                    qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

i had posted another question sometime back

i resolved the curtain animation part but am unable to change content dynamically now

i have two more html files second.html and third.html

the curtain needs to fall down before the content changes

after the curtain has hidden the text from view the content has to change

after the content has changed the curtain has to lift up to show the new content

Comment: What does it do currently? it looks close, just remove hide and show.

Comment: currently the gray curtain comes down and goes up perfectly but i expect the content to change before it goes up .. and it never happens

Comment: does the content never change, or does it go up before it changes

Comment: never changes .. i wish i could provide the source files ..

Comment: Have you watched the Ajax request/response in the browser's developer console? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: it sounds like your ajax response isn't returning what you expect it to return.

Comment: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: i just found out that it is working  in firefox .. why am i having problems with chrome may i ask ?